# Проверка массива на упорядоченность

Tags: c++, c

```
void Sorted(int arr[], int size)
{
     for (int i=0; i < size; i++) 
     {
         if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
         cout << "Array is not ordered" << ends;
         else
         cout << "Array is ordered" << ends;
         break;
     }
}
```

Не правильно работает проверка массива на упорядоченность по возрастанию, где ошибка?

Comment: тут несколько ошибок : 1. break; - сразу при первом же проходе цикла он выйдет из него
2. Результат надо выводить после цикла, а не в нем, используйте флаги (ветка else не нужна внутри цикла)

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке для этого имеется алгоритм [::std::is_sorted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы это отредактировал так:

```
void Sorted(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
         if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
         {
            cout << "Array is not ordered" << ends;
            return;
         }
    }
    cout << "Array is ordered" << ends;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что условие продолжения цикла i < size - 1 (иначе выйдете за границу массива на i+1), кроме того break заменен на return. А в вашем варианте break срабатывал после первой же итерации, что неверно (цикл не доходил до конца).